# How to use onScroll for View in Android

Tags: android, gesture, gesturedetector

I want to use the `onScroll` method of `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`.

So far I have this code:

```
public class TouchView extends View {
private Drawable image;
private float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
private GestureDetector simpleOnGestureListener;
private FrameLayout root;

public TouchView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    image = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wifi);
    setFocusable(true);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    simpleOnGestureListener = new GestureDetector(context,new MyGestureListener());
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    image.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    simpleOnGestureListener.onTouchEvent(event);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}


private class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,float distanceX, float distanceY){

        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to make the View scrollable/draggable.
So if I have two images drawn in the `View` and scroll, both drawings have to be scrolled.

I hope it's clear what I want to do!

Kind Regards!

Comment: you don't know when it is called?

Comment: what do you mean pskink? it's called every time I make a scroll gesture. What I don't know is WHAT to add in `onScroll` to make the View scroll

Comment: how to scroll the `View`? 1) open `View` documentation 2) ^F scroll

Comment: So I have to use `View.OnScrollChangeListener` instead of `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`? Am I right? or completely wrong?

Comment: no, you can use your detector if you want and inside `onScroll` scroll your View accordingly

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do. My question is where i can get the informations to know what I have to do for scrolling?

Comment: `android.view.View` documentation, everything is there, ^F `scrolling`

Comment: all right thank you!!!

Comment: Bitte schön (translated)

Answer (score 0):

Just make the top-level layout a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

  .......
  Your code            
  .......

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It's scrolling pages. You mentioned this one right..?!